# Sometimes Jwrapper app is not taking the updated build from the update url

Tags: jwrapper

Could you please help me out in the below situation.

Sometimes Jwrapper app is not taking the updated build from the update url specified in the jwrapper configuration file

Thanks
Venkatesh M

Answer (score 0):

Are you also uploading the supporting files like the -version.txt files for any changed archives?